# Semaphore timing out while accessing a serial port?

Tags: c#, timeout, serial-port, semaphore

I'm experiencing this problem while opening a serial port in C# (which should be dirt simple; or so I thought).

When I try to open a serial port, I am getting the following exception:

> The semaphore time-out period has expired.‎

Here is the method that is doing this.

```
public static void Open_TheActivePortWeWillUse(String Drone_StringNameFromUser)
{
    var TempSerialPort = new SerialPort (
        Drone_StringNameFromUser, 
        (int) SerialPortParameter.TheSerialPortSpeed);

    // Now we have a name that anybody can see and use
    OurSpecificPorts.TheActivePortWeAreUsing = TempSerialPort;      
    // We'll do 8-N-1 since almost the whole planet does that
    OurSpecificPorts.TheActivePortWeAreUsing.DataBits = 8;  
    // We'll do 8-N-1
    OurSpecificPorts.TheActivePortWeAreUsing.Parity = Parity.None;    
    // We'll do 8-N-1
    OurSpecificPorts.TheActivePortWeAreUsing.StopBits = StopBits.One;    

    OurSpecificPorts.TheActivePortWeAreUsing.DataReceived +=    
        OurBackGroundSerialPortReceiver;
    // We can now open our active port, which is what this line does
    OurSpecificPorts.TheActivePortWeAreUsing.Open();      
}
```

The strangest thing for me is that I get this error inconsistently. *Half the time it works okay*, and the other half, *it does not*.

Does anybody see anything obviously wrong with my code?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Declaring your SerialPort object inside the method will not allow access to it after the method closes.  Here is a method that works to open the port:

```
  private void OpenSerialPort(String portName)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            serialPort1.PortName = portName;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort1.RtsEnable = false;
            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            serialPort1.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not open serial port " + portName, "Error");
        }
    }
```

The SerialPort object is declared in the class:

```
namespace Arcadia
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private SerialPort serialPort1;
```

And the callback is added in the constructor:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.SerialPortReadCallback);
```

Sending data is handled in a different method:

```
    private void SerialPortWrite(String writeString)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.WriteLine(writeString);
        }
    }
```

And here is the received data callback:

```
    private void SerialPortReadCallback(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {

            while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                // Do something with the data

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler ?  I am declaring it in a class, and using methods in the class to send data. This is working; I have confirmed. I'm very interested in anything I'm doing that may come back to bite me later. Thanks for your input.   So, in your example, serialPort1 will be visible and available to all methods throughout the entire app ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the initialization, send, and receive methods.  In my example, yes, serialPort1 is available to all methods in the class (Form1).  It is not available to other classes.

Comment: I too experience erratic behavior of serial port with this error. What I have noticed is , it is related to USB (used as VCOM) driver and USB cable lose connections.